# Do updates run in the background on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: updates

When I was using an older version of Ubuntu, I used to see new updates installing all the time. On 13.04 I'm not sure if I was ever prompted for an update at all. However, there are settings like "Display immediately" or "Display weekly", so I assume I'm supposed to see when new updates are available. As far as I can tell, automatic updates are configured correctly.

Thank you

Comment: It could be that your sources.list is not configured correctly.

If you do a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` what do you see?

What is in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't it solve ur problem or not.... But there is some file that will help you.

> cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades

See there is entry at last .. Prompt.. Read this file and set as you like it.

Another directory that will help full.

> cd /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/

It contains all information regarding ur updates and upgrades.